# How can i optimize the for loop considering 500 request/sec

Tags: java, for-loop, optimization

How can I optimize my for loop:

```
public List<XYZ.Users> getUsers(
      List<ResponseDocument> responseDocuments
  ) {
    List<XYZ.Users> users = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ResponseDocument solrUser : responseDocuments) {
      Map<String, Object> field = solrUser.getFields();
      String name = field.getOrDefault(Constants.NAME, "").toString();
      int classId = (int) field.getOrDefault(Constants.ID, -1);
      XYZ.Users user = XYZ.Users.newBuilder()
          .setUser(name)
          .setId(classId)
          .setDir(Constants.DIR)
          .build();
      users.add(user);
    }
    return users;
  }
```

I track the time taken by this for loop in production ( 500 requests/sec) and I have seen some random spikes in time? I am not able to figure out why that might happen.

[image: Graph displaying the spike in this for loop]

What optimizations would you recommend?

Comment: You can use multi threading to divide data for each thread for creating your instance and add to list

Comment: Check when the garbage collector runs

Comment: @KaranjotSingh can you please share a sample?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you please explain more?

Comment: When the garbage collector runs reusing memory used by objects no longer needed, execution takes longer.  I would suggest VisualVM to get an initial insight in what is going on inside your JVM.

Comment: Is the map returned by `getFields` already existing? Is it being generated dynamically via Java Reflection?

Comment: Actually simply running a good profiler first against your code will allow you to figure out where the time is spent.  The code you've shown here, should not take that long on its own, so it is probably spent in methods called.  If you don't use Netbeans, visualvm is a good first choice until you have more advanced needs.